# Scatterplot with two different categories of data

Tags: r, scatterplot

I have a text document containing three columns.  One column is "sex", and each value is either "M" or "F".  The other two columns contain numerical data (my explanatory variable and response variable).

I want to create a Scatterplot in R where the point will look different for males than for females.  I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for advice on coding in R.

Comment: You need a small reproducible example - a small set of data in R that you call `dput` on so that people attempting an answer can make the same data. In `plot`, the `col` argument gives different colors, the `pch` argument can get different symbols (including letters).

Comment: Here's an example that uses both color and symbols `plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,iris,col=Species,pch=as.numeric(Species))` and heres one with color and letters `plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,iris,col=Species,pch=as.character(Species))` (but it's not so successful, since two species start with 'v')